# How do I sort a 2d array diagonally?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Before Sorting:

```
| 3 10 24  8|                      
|12 10 16 67|                       
|21 18 36 48|        
| 7  1 12 25|
```

After sorting:

```
|12  8  3  1|
|21 12 10  7|   
|36 24 16 10|     
|67 48 25 18|
```

As you can see, everything sorts diagonally. Below is the code I have
written, but as you can see it is far from complete.

```
      static int[][] diagonal(int[][] value, int n){
          int temp= 0;
          int a[][]; a= new int [n][n]; 
          for (int ai=0; ai<n;ai++)
              Arrays.sort(value[ai]);
          for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
              for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
                  a[i][n-1]=value[i][j];
       }
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), then please try to improve and specify your question.

Comment: Please clearly specify what precise problem you are facing

Comment: My problem is trying to go through the array in  diagonal order (specifically  the order shown above).

Comment: It's not clear what sorting "diagonally" means, though I see a possibility.  You should make sure *you* understand well enough to explain it clearly to others before you try to proceed, else it's unlikely that you'll be able to write code for it.

Comment: Generally, though, you could consider reading all the elements out into a right-length 1D array, sorting those linearly, and then writing them back into the original 2D array in the "diagonal" arrangement you need.

Comment: The logarithm to loop through the array diagonally is what I am having trouble with. Am I allowed to upload an image of my specific requirememnts?

Comment: No, I don't believe new users can do that.  Anyway, text is king, and moreover, if you cannot explain in your own words, then you probably don't understand the requirements well enough yet.

Comment: Looks you have hard time to phrase your requirements. At very least,if you post your image someone might help you to re-phrase your requirement. However, you have to expect more down votes.

Comment: I understand the problem and the algorithm, putting  in to code it being hard. I have edited my question, hopefully this helps. The sorting starts at the very right, and slowly works its way to the bottom left corner. And then it expands diagonally downwards.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, what I understand is that you are having trouble to rearrange the elements of a 1-D array to a 2-D array in a diagonal sequence.

You can use the following code to do this arranging:

```
int sorted1d[SIZE]; // the sorted 1-D array suggested in comments
int l=0; // for accessing the 1-D array
int i2,j2;

for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    for(j=0,i2=i;j<n && i2<n;i2++,j++){
        output[i2][j] = sorted1d[l];
        l++;
    }

for(j=1;j<n;j++)
    for(j2=j,i=0;j2<n && i<n;i++,j2++){
        output[i][j2] = sorted1d[l];
        l++;
    }
```

Hope that this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but I will make some observations that will help you with your stated problem of iterating through the 2D array in the needed order.

In the first place, observe that the iteration runs over several distinct "bands" of the matrix, from top, left toward bottom, right within each band.  For an *n* x *n* array, there *n* such bands whose first element is on the top edge, and *n* whose first element is on the left edge, but that counts the main diagonal twice; there are therefore 2 * *n* - 1 total bands.  Given an array element `a[i][j]`, if `i + 1` and `j + 1` are less than *n* then `a[i + 1][j + 1]` is the next element of that band.

Bands can be characterized by their distance and direction from the main diagonal.  The main diagonal itself, with first element `a[0][0]`, has distance 0 from itself.  The band with first element `a[0][1]` has distance 1, and that with first element `a[3][0]` has distance 3 in the negative direction (because `a[0][-3]` would be in that band if it existed).

To iterate through the whole array in diagonal fashion, you want to iterate over each band in turn, from the one with the greatest positive distance from the main diagonal (*n* - 1) to the one with the greatest negative distance (1 - *n*).  Each band has *n* - abs(`distance`) elements; the first is `a[0][distance]` if `distance` is non-negative, and `a[-distance][0]` if `distance` is non-positive.

Answer (score -1):

Here I coded a solution: https://repl.it/GHEd

It works. I'm not a Java ninja (I like Ruby :) ) so maybe there are some things that can be done better.

Anyway I tried to make the code self explanatory.

You can read @JohnBollinger's answer to try to understand the algorithm.

Some results I used:

- a square matrix of dimension `n` has `(n-1)*2 + 1` diagonals.
- the following equation is true: `diagonal = line + column`. Write a matrix with positions as values and you will see it.

If you need further explanation tell me what you don't understand and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Do not do others' homework for them.  It is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: I get your point. But I believe it's still a valid question for the tag **algorithm**. The implementation is just a bonus to verify the algorithm.